# Function not defined at HTMLSelectElement.onchange

Tags: javascript, html, scale, onchange, openlayers-3

I'm doing a scale selector in Openlayers.
I've tested it in a single HTML file and it works. But now I want to put it in a map designed with a tree panel.
I've a HTML file where I have the select tag:

```
        <select id="scalecombo" onchange="scaleCombo(this.value)">
            <option value="50">50</option>
            <option value="66.57305752688175">67</option>
            <option value="100">100</option>
            <option value="150">150</option>
        </select>
```

After this, I have the call to the file where I have the function scaleCombo:

```
<script>
        Ext.Loader.setConfig({
            enabled: true,
            paths: {'GeoExt': 'geoext3/src'}
        });

        //Definición de la proyección ESPG:25830//
        var myprojname='EPSG:25830';
        proj4.defs(myprojname, "+proj=utm +zone=30 +elips=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs");
        var myprojection = ol.proj.get(myprojname);
</script>
<script src="visor.js"></script>
<script src="js/layers.js"></script>
```

just before the tag of the end of the body.

In the file "visor.js" is the definition of the map and the scaleCombo function:

```
function scaleCombo(sel) {
     var units = view.getProjection().getUnits();
     var dpi = 25.4 / 0.28;
     var mpu = ol.proj.METERS_PER_UNIT[units];
     var scale = sel.value;
     var resolution = scale / mpu / 39.37 / dpi;
     view.setResolution(resolution);
}
```

The error shown is: "Uncaught ReferenceError: scaleCombo is not defined
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange ".

I think that the problem is that the select onchange tag looks for the scaleCombo function and it doesn't find it because the call of the function is after the select tag, but the function needs view.getProjection().getUnits().
Is there any way to avoid this?

The code of visor.js is:

```
Ext.require([
  'GeoExt.component.Map',
  'GeoExt.data.store.LayersTree'
]);

 var mapComponent;
 var mapPanel;
 var treePanel;



Ext.application({
  name: 'BasicTree',
  launch: function() {

    var olMap;
    var treeStore;

    cargarnomen();

    olMap = new ol.Map({
        layers: [layerorto2016gv, layerlim, layerwfsnomen],
        controls: ol.control.defaults({ 
            attribution: false 
            }).extend([
                attribution,
                //Define the default controls
                new ol.control.Zoom(),
                new ol.control.MousePosition({
                    coordinateFormat: function (coordinates) {
                        var coord_x = coordinates[0].toFixed(3);
                        var coord_y = coordinates[1].toFixed(3);
                        return 'ETRS89 UTM30: ' + coord_x + ', ' + coord_y;
                    },
                    projection: 'EPSG:25830',

                }),
            ]),
            view: new ol.View({
                center: ol.proj.transform([-2.90, 43.015], 'EPSG:4326', myprojname),
                projection: myprojection,
                zoom: 12
            })

    });


    /*Código del selector de escalas*/
    /*Escala actual del mapa*/
    var view = olMap.getView();
    var resolution = view.getResolution();
    var units = view.getProjection().getUnits();
    var dpi = 25.4 / 0.28;
    var mpu = ol.proj.METERS_PER_UNIT[units];
    var scale = resolution * mpu * 39.37 * dpi;

    /*Si la vista se modifica, calcula la nueva escala y la muestra*/
    olMap.getView().on('change:resolution', function (evt) {
        var resolution = evt.target.get('resolution');

        var units = view.getProjection().getUnits();
        var dpi = 25.4 / 0.28;
        var mpu = ol.proj.METERS_PER_UNIT[units];
        var scale = resolution * mpu * 39.37 * dpi;
        console.log(scale);
        var element = document.getElementById('scalecombo');
        element.value = scale;
        scale = Math.round(scale) ;

        document.getElementById('scale').innerHTML = "Scale = 1 : " + scale;
    });


    document.getElementById('scalecombo').addEventListener('change', scaleCombo, true)      
    function scaleCombo(sel) {
        var units = view.getProjection().getUnits();
        var dpi = 25.4 / 0.28;
        var mpu = ol.proj.METERS_PER_UNIT[units];
        var scale = sel.value;
        var resolution = scale / mpu / 39.37 / dpi;

        view.setResolution(resolution);
    }


    /*Creación de los paneles y del mapa*/
    mapComponent = Ext.create('GeoExt.component.Map', {
        map: olMap
    });

    mapPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        region: 'center',
        border: false,
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [mapComponent]
    });


    treeStore = Ext.create('GeoExt.data.store.LayersTree', {
        layerGroup: olMap.getLayerGroup()
    });

    treePanel = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
        title: 'CAPAS',
        viewConfig: {
            plugins: {ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop'}
        },
        store: treeStore,
        rootVisible: false,
        flex: 1,
        border: false

    });

    var MainViewport = new Ext.Viewport ({
        layout: 'border',
        items: [ 
            mapPanel,

            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                region: 'east',
                width: 400,
                layout: {
                    type: 'vbox',
                    align: 'stretch'
                },
                items: [
                    treePanel,
                    map
                ]
            },

        ]
    });



}
```

});

I have changed line 74, just before "function scaleCombo(sel)"

Comment: can you post the whole visor.js code?

Comment: if i use document.getElementById('scalecombo').addEventListener('change', scaleCombo, true) I get the error: Uncaught qa {message: "Assertion failed. See https://openlayers.org/en/v4.1.0/doc/errors/#32 for details.", code: 32, name: "AssertionError"}